# How to find number of occurences of particular characters in sequential order

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find the number of occurrences of a particular string within a group of characters. The letters in the string do not need to be next to each other but must appear in sequential order.

For example, the following sequence contains four occurrences of the string "abc"

Sequence "aabcc"

Occurrences:

**a** a **b** **c** c

**a** a **b** c **c**

a **a** **b** **c** c

a **a** **b** c **c**

Any help with how to match without consuming characters? I was trying to use regex and match but I'm not sure if it's possible. I'm writing this for php

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/nUbHe)

```
<?php

$sequence = "aabbcc";
$occurrences = array();

$sequences = str_split($sequence);
// dn($sequences);
$sequences_amount = array();

foreach ($sequences as $key => $char) {
    if(!isset($sequences_amount[$char])){
        $sequences_amount[$char] = 1;
    }else{
        $sequences_amount[$char]++;
    }

}

var_dump($sequences_amount);

function sequenceCount($data = array())
{
    if(!isset($data) || empty($data) || (count($data) == 0))return;

    $count = NULL;

    foreach ($data as $char => $amount) {
        if($count == NULL){
            $count = $amount;
        }else{
            $count = $count * $amount;
        }
    }

    return $count;
}

$count = sequenceCount($sequences_amount);
echo("\n\nResult:\n");

echo($count);
```