# PHP - Array from User Input

Tags: php, arrays, string, user-input

I have tried for about three days and I just cannot figure this out.
The goal is to have the user input numbers and have it filter out the unique numbers. Say the user inputs the numbers: 24, 24, 56, 23, 1, 3, 24 - the output should be 24, 56, 23, 1, 3. Up to this point, everything appears to be working. The only thing is when I hit the submit button, it doesn't return any values.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--    e9_1.php
    Project1.php
    -->
    <html lang = "en">
    <head> 
      <title> Project1.php </title>
      <meta charset = "utf-8" />
      <?php

      function unique($strings) {
         $uniqueStrings = array();
         foreach ($strings as $string) {
            foreach ($uniqueStrings as $uString) {
               if ($string == $uString) break;
               if(isset($_POST[‘numbers’])){
                  $str=preg_split("/[\s,]", $_POST['numbers']);
               }
            }
            if ($string != $uString)
               $uniqueStrings[] = $string;
         }
         return $uniqueStrings;
      }
      ?>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $str = array();
    $uStr=unique($str);
    foreach ($uStr as $st)
    print ("$st <br />");
    ?>

    <br>
    Enter Numbers: <br>
    <form method = "POST">
    <input type="text" name="numbers"/>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" />

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: One problem is that you're passing an empty array to your `unique()` function.

Comment: And are those curly quotes on `$_POST[‘numbers’]` in your actual code, or is that just a copy/paste problem?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, I saw the same like you. So your eyes are OK ! :D

Comment: https://3v4l.org/JDa9o I tested code, it has error in line 6: `foreach ($strings as $string)`

Comment: this `preg_split("/[\s,]"` will throw a __warning__: `preg_split(): No ending delimiter '/' found on line x`

Comment: @Monstre, I think you can refer from this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52921803/6351894 , and change for your problem.

Comment: @Monstre Here is the [simple code](https://3v4l.org/Dn15H) for `unique` function

Comment: @NgocNam If you feel you have an appropiate answer (as your snipped could be), you could write it as an answer!

Comment: @Jeff, Thank you, I lack time a little for writing the answer. :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working snippet for your task. I've re-written most of it.

```
<?php

//$_POST['numbers'] = " 24, 24, 56, 23, 1, 3, 24";

function getNumbers($string) {
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s]/","",$string); // remove all possible space, tabs, etc
    $n = explode(",", $string); // a simple explode will be enough then
    return $n;
}

$numbers=array_unique(getNumbers($_POST['numbers'])); // finally use array_unique() to get rid of the doubles.

var_dump($numbers);

// OUTPUT:
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "24"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "56"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "23"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

Snippet can be found here: https://3v4l.org/BK0eU

The problems in your code were:

- empty array as input to function unique
- preg_replace missing end delimiter
- `$_POST[‘numbers’]` with curly quotes
- coding a function that is already there (array_unique) ...

Note: This simple function does not yet check if there was other input than numbers and commas.

Comment: Sorry if some of my answer is redundant with yours. I just had a slightly different take on it. I think we all agree that reimplementing array_unique is probably not the way to go, though.

Comment: all good! I guess it's also good for others to see different implementations of the same task to pick for their specific needs. And you gave me a thumbs up ;) (as I did for your answer)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the user input from a single text input.

```
<input type="text" name="numbers"/>
```

That means `$_POST['numbers']` is going to be a string, not an array, so your `unique` function needs to take a string.

If you're looking for unique numbers, it's probably better to do a positive match for sequences of digits rather than splitting on whitespace, or anything else, for that matter.

Your function is quite complex, when PHP already has the `array_unique` function. It should just be a matter of matching the numbers in the string and running the resulting array through `array_unique`. Also, I would recommend not referencing a superglobal like `$_POST` in a helper function like that. If you want it to be reusable, it should take its input as an argument rather than depending on a global value.

Based on all that, I'd write the function like this:

```
function unique_numbers(string $input): array
{
    preg_match_all('/\d+/', $input, $matches);
    return array_unique($matches[0]);
}
```

and call it with the posted string

```
$numbers = unique_numbers($_POST['numbers']);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about utilize PHP functions to make it simpler?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head> 
  <title> Project1.php </title>
  <meta charset = "utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['numbers'])) {

        $strings = $_POST['numbers'];
        $str = explode(",", $strings);
        $uStr=array_unique($str);
        echo implode(",", $uStr);
    }
    ?>

    <br>
    Enter Numbers: <br>
    <form method = "POST">
    <input type="text" name="numbers"/>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" />

</body>
</html>
```